# How would I be able to get the value from the example below using Selenium Python?

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver

I would like to enter the value "EU 41" and I want it to click on the button. The class name for both EU 40.5 and EU 41 is the same. Is there any way I can just select EU 41?

```html
button type="button" class="size-grid-dropdown size-grid-button" data-qa="size-dropdown">EU 40.5</button>
button type="button" class="size-grid-dropdown size-grid-button" data-qa="size-dropdown">EU 41</button>
```

Comment: Hi! Please show us what you've tried so far

Comment: I tried using the text but it didn't seem to work. I don't have much knowledge yet so it would be nice it someone would show me how to use it. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

This xpath will match the button by text:

```
//button[contains(text(),'EU 41')]
```

You would be using it in something like:

```
driver.find_element_by_xpath("//button[contains(text(),'EU 41')]").click()
```

Answer (score 0):

Try other find_element_by_... like XPath.